# Escaping ampersand from an external variable in a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

**What I want the script to do:**

I need to rename a .mkv video file created by Handbrake by removing the -1 suffix, which Handbrake adds, then delete the original source video file which has the exact same name (minus the -1), but also potentially a different file extension.

Some caveats:

- I'm using Windows SendTo to pass the source file as an external variable to the script
- The source video file and file directory may contain spaces, ampersands and parentheses
- Source files may be of different extensions such as .mp4, .mkv, .wmv, .mov
- Directory locations of the files are not fixed
- Batch script will not be executed within the same directory as the files
- Use [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)'s `clonefiletime` command to copy the original file's time attributes to the new file
- Use NirCmd's `moverecyclebin` command to move the file to recycle bin rather than using **del** command

**Example and expected behaviour**

```
Directory: C:\Test test\

Files:
Test File & final (test)-1.mkv - Handbrake created file I want to rename
Test File & final (test).mp4 - original source file I want to delete
Test File & final.mp4
Test File.mp4
Otherfile.mp4
Another File.wmv
DifferentFile (1234).mkv
```

In this scenario, the time attributes of `Test File & final (test).mp4` are copied over to `Test File & final (test)-1.mkv`, `Test File & final (test).mp4` is then moved to the recycle bin and finally `Test File & final (test)-1.mkv` is renamed to `Test File & final (test).mkv`.

**Code I have so far:**

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET source=%1
FOR %%z IN (!source!) DO (
  SET fpath=%%~dpz
  SET filename=%%~nz
  SET ext=%%~xz
  SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
  )
  (
    ENDLOCAL
    SET "fpath=%fpath%"
    SET "filename=%filename%"
    SET "fileprune=%fileprune%"
    SET "ext=%ext%"
    SET "fixed=%fileprune%%ext%"
    
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b "%fpath%" ^| findstr /L /E /C:"%fileprune%.mp4" /C:"%fileprune%.wmv" /C:"%fileprune%.mkv" /C:"%fileprune%.mov"') DO (
  REM use NirCmd to copy the timestamp of the original file over to new file
  nircmdc clonefiletime "%fpath%%%a" %source%
  REM use NirCmd to move old file to recycle bin instead of del command as a failsafe measure
  nircmdc moverecyclebin "%fpath%%%a"
)
FOR %%b IN ("%fixed%") DO (
  REN %source% "%%~nxb"
)
EXIT
```

**The problem:**

The script fails for filenames which contain ampersands and I believe there's an issue with spaces, in that Windows automatically adds quotes around the file path and name which contains them.

For example `"C:\Test test\Test File & final (test)-1.mkv"` is quoted automatically when using Windows SendTo and I read surrounding the entire variable with double quotes would resolve the ampersand issue, but it would become `SET "source="C:\Test test\Test File & final (test)-1.mkv""` which also breaks the script.

I've also tried doing `SET "source=%~1"`, but it then breaks the first FOR loop - example output below:

```
C:\Test test>(
SET fpath=C:\
 SET filename=Test
 SET ext=
 SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
)

C:\Test test>(
SET fpath=C:\Test test\test\
 SET filename=Test
 SET ext=
 SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
)

C:\Test test>(
SET fpath=C:\Test test\
 SET filename=File
 SET ext=
 SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
)

C:\Test test>(
SET fpath=C:\Test test\
 SET filename=&
 SET ext=
 SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
)

C:\Test test>(
SET fpath=C:\Test test\
 SET filename=final
 SET ext=
 SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
)

C:\Test test>(
SET fpath=C:\Test test\
 SET filename=(test)-1
 SET ext=.mkv
 SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
)

C:\Test test>(
ENDLOCAL
 SET "fpath=C:\Test test\"
 SET "filename=(test)-1"
 SET "fileprune=(test)"
 SET "ext=.mkv"
 SET "fixed=(test).mkv"
)
```

The code is a mess since I know nothing about coding, but I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `set "source=%~1"` to remove potential quotes, then use `for %%z in ("!source!") do (…)`; since you are never using plain `%%z` but always some `~`-modifier (like `%%~nz`), quotes become once again removed at this point…

Comment: Thanks aschipfl, that actually was a relatively simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to aschipfl and T3RR0R for pointing out I was missing double quotes around some variables.

**Revised code:**

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "source=%~1"
FOR %%z IN ("!source!") DO (
  SET nsource=%%~dpnxz
  SET fpath=%%~dpz
  SET filename=%%~nz
  SET ext=%%~xz
  SET fileprune=!filename:~0,-2!
  )
  (
    ENDLOCAL
    SET "nsource=%nsource%"
    SET "fpath=%fpath%"
    SET "filename=%filename%"
    SET "fileprune=%fileprune%"
    SET "ext=%ext%"
    SET "fixed=%fileprune%%ext%"
    
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b "%fpath%" ^| findstr /L /E /C:"%fileprune%.mp4" /C:"%fileprune%.wmv" /C:"%fileprune%.mkv" /C:"%fileprune%.mov"') DO (
  REM use NirCmd to copy the timestamp of the original file over to new file
  nircmdc clonefiletime "%fpath%%%a" "%nsource%"
  REM use NirCmd to move old file to recycle bin instead of del command as a failsafe measure
  nircmdc moverecyclebin "%fpath%%%a"
)
FOR %%b IN ("%fixed%") DO (
  REN "%nsource%" "%%~nxb"
)
EXIT
```

Answer (score 2):

by doublequoting the definition of all variables, and manipulation of the environment properties troublesome characters can be processed within a for loop.

by assigning the initial value to the variable in an environment where delayed expansion is disabled, troublesome characters can be preserved including `!`

Delayed expansion can then be enabled to safely perform substring modification regardless of poison characters.

an example:

```bat
@Echo off & CD "%~dp0" 
 Setlocal DisableDelayedexpansion
 Set "demofile=test!^!&~.txt"
 Break >"%demofile%"
 For %%G in ("test!*.txt")Do (
  Set "Filepath=%%~nG"
  Call :Sub Filepath
 )
 Set Filepath
 del "%demofile%"
Goto :Eof
:sub
 Set /A i+=1 + 0
 Setlocal EnableDelayedexpansion
 Set "_tmp=!%1!"
 Set "_tmp=!_tmp:&=^&!"
 Endlocal & Set "%1[%i%]=%_tmp%"
 Set %1=
Goto :Eof
```

Comment: method modified to prevent caret doubling when sub is called.

Comment: Nice, but you can use `set "_tmp=!%1!"` instead of  `Call Set "_tmp=%%%1%%"`

Comment: you are indeed correct, joys of overthinking things, I presumed the `!` would attempt to expand in the delayed expansion environment without actually testing it.